# Why does my CSS button move the neighbouring button when :active?

Tags: html, css

I have these buttons inside a div, next to each other.
When I click one of them the margin is adjusted to resemble the button getting pressed.
But this moves the button next to it aswell, and I can't figure out why.

Doesn't matter how big the wrapping div is.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hustlerinc/jtnTJ/1/). Can anyone help me get this fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to both `button.demo` and `button.source`: http://jsfiddle.net/jtnTJ/14/